# How to convert Observable<string>[] to Observable<string[]>

Tags: rxjs-observables

I’ve got an Observable that has an array of objects and I would like to convert them to a different object using a second observable. This is part of a larger project so to simplify this for my question I am going to have an observable that has an array of number and I would like to convert them to a string. I started with the following.

```
    const response$ = of({results: [1, 2, 3]});
    response$.pipe(
        map((response) => {
            return response.results.map((id) => {
                return id.toString();
            })
        })
    )
    .subscribe((response: string[]) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

The response in the subscribe will be an array of string as expected. Now I need to use a second observable to convert the number to string (again just to make the question simpler). So I replaced `return id.toString()` with `return of(id.toString())` to simulate making a second call to an observable.

```
    const response$ = of({results: [1, 2, 3]});
    response$.pipe(
        map((response) => {
            return response.results.map((id) => {
                return of(id.toString());
            })
        }),
    )
    .subscribe((response: Observable<string>[]) => {
        
    })
```

Now the signature of the response is `Observable<string>[]` but I need the response to be `string[]` so I started reading about other RxJS operators and I ended up with the following.

```
    const response$ = of({results: [1, 2, 3]});
    response$.pipe(
        concatMap((response) => {
            return response.results.map((id) => {
                return of(id.toString());
            })
        }),
        concatAll()
    )
    .subscribe((response: string) => {
        console.log('bar', response);
    })
```

I used `concatMap()` and `concatAll()` because I need the call to the second observable to happen in sequence. The problem now is that my response is a string and I get three calls to the subscriber `“1”` `“2”` `“3”`. I need one response of `string[]`. Can someone explain how to take an `Observable<string>[]` and convert it to `Observable<string[]>` in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
const response$ = of({results: [1, 2, 3]});
response$.pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
        // map array to observables and execute all with forkJoin
        return forkJoin(...response.results.map((id) => {
            return of(id.toString());
        }))
    })
)
.subscribe((response: string) => {
    console.log('bar', response);
})
```

however, this is going to execute in parallel. if you need sequential execution on the inner, you can use `concat` and `reduce`

```
const response$ = of({results: [1, 2, 3]});
response$.pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
        // map array to observables and execute all with concat and collect results with reduce
        return concat(...response.results.map((id) => {
            return of(id.toString());
        })).pipe(reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat([v]), []))
    })
)
.subscribe((response: string) => {
    console.log('bar', response);
})
```

only thing to be careful of is to make sure `response.results` has items in it. may need a length check like:

```
if (!response.results.length)
  return of([])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I did look at forkJoin() but it will process in parallel not sequence right? Also its shows depreciated at rxjs6 in VSCode but does not say its deprecated (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin). I think concat() will run in sequence, right?

Comment: `forkJoin` is not deprecated. but yes it is parallel execution, i added what you need to do for seequential.

Comment: that is really nice. Can you explain what the three dots (...) does in the concat() method? I am familiar with the spread operator but I think this is something different.

Comment: It’s just converting the array to arguments to the function. I’m honestly not sure if it needs to be there anymore since RXJs has changed their interfaces a few times and it’s more flexible now but it used to be needed and I do it out of habit.

Comment: Well I tried it with out the three dots and it returns Observable<string>[].